# Choosing a row from a table using pyramid

Tags: python, html, pyramid

I would like to construct (constructing a table is easy, I do it inside templates) a table and choose a row from it. I am using pyramid as a framework and I think somehow I need to make the templates talk to the model, but I am not sure how. Can someone show me an example or direct me to link where I can see an explanation and an example (I couldn't find one). This is my HTML for the table:

```
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Course Number</th>
      <th>Course Name</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>111</td>
      <td>What ever the name is</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: I did not understand what do you really want to do... But I'm sure you can do this with ajax requests. Be more clarified. Please, give an example of result you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

Making some assumptions, what you describe would be handled via ajax, which is a technology based on javascript, and outside the scope of they Pyramid framework but easily added. Below is a very simple example of what the HTML might look like.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.row').bind('click',function(){
          var row = $(this);
          options = {
              url:"/some_pyramid_url_to_a_view/",
              type:"get",
              data:{'row_id':$(this).attr('id')},
              success:function(event){$(row).text(event.data.method_result)},
              error:function(){alert('error')},
              dataType:'json'
          }
          $.ajax(options);
      });
  });
</script>
  </head>
    <body>
      <table>
        <tr id="${row.id}" class="row">
          <td>Row</td>
        </tr>
    </body>
</html>
```

The code between the  tags is the javascript, here I am using the jQuery library to create the ajax call to the url '/some_pyramid_url_to_a_view/' which is tied to the view function 'some_pyramid_view'. I'm binding a click event to the row element in the table using the jQuery selector on the class 'row' "$('.row').bind('click',..." the event is then handled by the function block "function(){...}" immediately following. I'm setting up the call in the options object and passing the row id in the data "data:{'row_id':$(this).attr('id')}," where the code "$(this).attr('id')" is accessing the id set in the template '...' Finally I send of the request to the view using '$.ajax(options)'.

```
import json

@view_config(xhr=True)
def some_pyramid_view(request):
    json_dict = dict()
    session = DBSession()
    if request.method == 'GET':
         row_id = request.GET['row_id']
         row = session.query(Row).get(row_id)
         json_dict['method_result'] = row.some_method_call()
    return Response(json.dumps(json_dict))
```

There is another piece here, JSON is being used to communicate back to the javascript from the Pyramid view. JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation and is a data-interchange format. I create a Python dictionary and using the 'json' package convert it to JSON which I send back to the 'success' call back function in the javascript with the results of the method call. In the success call back function I update the text in the table row with the result of the method call in the view. '$(row).text(event.data.method_result)'

This might be more than you were expecting but it is well worth learning how to use ajax to add functionality to your websites.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that pyramid really has nothing to do with the question. The problem with web frameworks is that it's hard for new users to know what is responsible for what. So it's always good to point out where those boundaries are. pyramid takes http requests and generates http responses. pyramid does not negate the need for a user to learn javascript/css/html/ajax etc.... and it doesn't put any restrictions on it either. So pyramid is but one tool you use to build a web application.